# Eliminating Words Based On Letters

Tags: python

I have a dictionary and an alphabet:

```
import string
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
dictionary = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("dictionary.txt")]
```

In a function, I remove a letter from the alphabet

```
alphabet.remove(letter)
```

Now, I want to filter through the dictionary to eliminate words if they contain a letter not in the alphabet.

I tried for loops:

```
for term in dictionary:
        for char in term:
            print term, char
            if char not in alphabet:
                dictionary.remove(term)
                break
```

However, this skips over certain words.
I tried filter:

```
dictionary = filter(term for term in dictionary for char in term if char not in alphabet)
```

But I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

Comment: What about the function supplied to filter?

Comment: **dictionary** has a very specific meaning in Python.  Consider using another variable name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to modify a list (or really any container) while you are iterating over it.  This can result in errors where it seems like some items are being skipped.  If you make a copy (`dictionary[:]`), it should work out...

```
for term in dictionary[:]:
    for char in term:
        print term, char
        if char not in alphabet:
            dictionary.remove(term)
            break
```

We can probably do better here too ...

```
alphabet_set = set(alphabet)  # set membership testing is faster than string/list...
new_dictionary = [
    term for term in dictionary
    if all(c in alphabet_set for c in term)]
```

<sup><sup>Also, it's probably wise to avoid the name `dictionary` for a `list` instance since `dict` is actually a builtin type...</sup></sup>